# How to migrate from cellar clever cloud to S3 of Amazon

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, clever-cloud

I am still new to the cloud and when I first started I used Clever Cloud.
But now I want to migrate to AWS, and I have data that I want to move from Cellar to Amazon S3.
I am not sure what are the conventions on this or the best practices, and if anyone can help with documentation or explanation on how I can proceed is very much appreciated.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Clever Cloud Cellar](https://www.clever-cloud.com/cellar-s3-hosting/) is an Amazon S3 compatible service. This means it operates pretty much the same as S3.

Clever Cloud is not able to communicate directly to Amazon S3, and Amazon S3 is not able to communicate directly to Cellar. Therefore, you will need to:

- **Download the files** from Cellar using `s3cmd` or the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) (see instructions on [CleverCloud Cellar website](https://www.clever-cloud.com/doc/deploy/addon/cellar/))
- **Upload the files** to an Amazon S3 bucket using the AWS CLI and your AWS credentials

This activity would be most efficient if performed from an **Amazon EC2 instance** since it has high bandwidth connectivity to Amazon S3.

Note that there will be Data Transfer costs from Clever Cloud for "Outbound traffic".

I suggest you start by getting `s3cmd` or the AWS CLI working with Cellar to download a single file, and then get the AWS CLI working with Amazon S3 to upload a single file. You can then use the `sync` command to copy whole directories of files.